# Can't get mvcMiniProfiler to show up

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvc-mini-profiler, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to throw together a site pretty quickly, and so I enlisted the help of [Twitter's Bootstrap project](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), which has been a lifesaver for a non-designer like me.

I'm now attempting to get the MiniProfiler up and running (it looks awesome!) but am having some trouble getting it to display and I hope someone can help me catch my (likely simple) mistake. This is the most basic of basic scenarios, and as far as I can tell I'm following the recommendations of the MiniProfiler site.

**global.asax:**

```
using MvcMiniProfiler;
    ...
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
//profile for every request while site is in dummy mode
        MiniProfiler.Start();
}

protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    MiniProfiler.Stop();
}
```

**The Controller I'm attempting to profile:**

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
    using (profiler.Step("Wassappp?"))
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Heyyy there! Testing MiniProfiler.";
        using (profiler.Step("Doing a pointless for loop!"))
        {
            int result;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                result = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

**The relevant section of my _layout.cshtml page:**

```
@using MvcMiniProfiler;
...
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.3.0/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/site_bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()

  </head>
```

Any ideas? The site displays exactly fine, but without any sort of MiniProfiler action.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: what do you see in firebug? what js and css files has it pulled down?

Comment: are you on IIS6 or have the application pool configured in classic mode?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the Twitter Bootstrap package I made http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MahApps.Twitter.Bootstrap and then the MiniProfiler.MVC package   http://nuget.org/List/Packages/MiniProfiler.MVC3  and then made sure the RenderIncludes line was below the CSS definitions and it worked fine.

I'd try a shortcut and make sure you're using the MVC package of Miniprofiler.